# Centos 7 Avahi doesn't resolve from windows machines

Tags: centos, samba, centos7, mdns, avahi

I have installed and configured avahi-daemon and samba on Centos 6.6 and it's working when I am testing it from an Ubuntu machine. e.g.: `ping myhostname.local` or `smb://myhostname.local`

However, when I try from a windows machine, neither samba works nor I can ping it via `ping myhostname`

Can anyone please explain me the possible difference between what Windows does and what Ubuntu does.

Besides, it would be great if Windows could list my server when browsing network, but I don't know if I should enable something like a broadcast or just normal configuration is adequate.

Thanks a log in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just post an answer to the same question on serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/711619/centos-7-avahi-doesnt-resolve-from-windows-machines